# Espaço em branco no menu com bootstrap

Tags: css

Boa tarde,

Eu estou tentando dividir um menu com uma linha branca no meio com css.

Eu consegui fazer, porém do lado direito o menu fica com um espaço sem a linha e no itens que estão abaixo fica a linha branca também meio que pegando a borda do menu.

[image: Menu]

O código CSS:

```
#menu .nav li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid White;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin: 0;
```

}

HTML:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    {% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.children %}
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {% for child in children %}
            <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          {% endfor %}</div>
        <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a> </div>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Podia colocar  tbm o Html para podermos ver, já tentou usar a classe divider do bootstrap?

Comment: @Leandro Coloquei o HTML, antes não tinha conseguido postar, não tentei usar, eu coloco ela direto no HTML como classe da div ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, declara ela normal dentro de uma div, ou, até mesmo dentro de um span, não sei nunca tentei, sem precisar criar uma outra div. Tipo class=divider

Comment: @Leandro eu tentei, mas não funcionou

Answer (score 1):

O problema é no tamanho do elemento, previamente posso dizer que o elemento .navbar-collapse.collapse não está ocupando o tamanho total da .navbar, se isto estiver correto, faça da seguinte forma:

`.navbar-collapse.collapse { 
    padding-left: 0; 
    padding-right: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    width: 100% 
}`

Comment: Eu fiz o teste, se for uma resolução menor que a padrão do meu pc até funciona, mas se for a normal continua com erro, obrigado por ajudar